# Reuse CTE after For LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

In the procedure i'm writing, I execute several steps. In the previous version of the procedure, multiple steps inserted data into tables that were misused as temporary data. However, the data i'm inserting is larger than the max columnsize of the table (NVARCHAR2 (2000)). That's why I'm rewriting the procedure to use CTE's instead of filing the tables. I rewrote the forloop I'm using to match the template as shown in this question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517772/use-for-loop-after-the-with-clause-in-pl-sql). However, the next step of the procedure should use the same CTE data. How do I access this? How do I merge the part after 'Step8' from the code with the above?

Anonimised part of my code:

```
FOR rec IN (.
WITH ELEMENT_CTE (Row1, Row2, Row3)
AS
(
...
)
,

EXPRESSIONS_CTE(Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4) 
AS
(
...
)

SELECT Row1,Row2, Row3, Row4 FROM EXPRESSIONS_CTE ) 

LOOP
    IF rec.Row1 = '3' THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO SCHEMA.CMW_TABLENAMEONE...;
    COMMIT;
    ELSIF rec.Row1 = '5' THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO SCHEMA.CMW_TABLENAMETWO...;
    COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

-- Step 8 
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.CMW_TABLENAMEONE (T1Row1, T1Row2, T1Row3)
SELECT DISTINCT Row1
     , Row2
     , NULL Row3
FROM EXPRESSIONS_CTE
WHERE Row1 = 3
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT T1Row1
     , T1Row2
     , NULL T1Row3
FROM SCHEMA.CMW_TABLENAMEONE
;
```

Comment: Scope of the CTE is limited to the query only.

Answer (score 2):

If you frequently use the same CTE, why wouldn't you create a **view** instead and use it *everywhere*? That would also *solve* your current problem.